# Show multiple div depending on select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please see the image for visual understanding
[Visual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yctHz.png)

```
<div class="Property Type">
    <label for=""><input type="radio" name="property_type" value="residential"> Residential</label>
    <label for=""><input type="radio" name="property_type" value="commercial"> Commercial</label>
</div>
    <!-- residential and commercial div will show when property type selected -->
<div id="residential">
     <select name="" id="">
         <option value="1">Apartment</option>
         <option value="2">Becholor</option>
         <option value="3">Sublet</option>
     </select>
</div>
<div id="commercial">
     <select name="" id="">
         <option value="4">Floor</option>
         <option value="5">Land</option>
         <option value="6">Hotel</option>
     </select>
</div>
<!-- if bechelor and sublet select then show room type and member -->
<div id="f-type">
    <select name="" id="">
        <option value="room">Room</option>
        <option value="seat">Seat</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="gender">
    <select name="" id="">
        <option value="family">Family</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
<!-- price will show when apartment, land, floor -->
<div class="price">
    <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Unit"> Unit
    <input type="text" placeholder="per unit price"> Price per unit
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.property_type input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
   if($(this).attr('value') == 'residential') {
      $('#residential').show(); 
      $('.property_type .res').addClass(" btn-warning"); 
        $('#commercial').hide(); 
      $('.property_type .com').removeClass(" btn-warning"); 
      }
       else {
         $('#commercial').show(); 
        $('.property_type .com').addClass(" btn-warning"); 
      $('#residential').hide(); 
       $('.property_type .res').removeClass(" btn-warning"); 
      }
 });
$('.property_type input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  if($(this).attr('value') == 'bechelor') {
 $('#f-type').show(); 
     $('#gender').show(); 
                                      
    }
      else {
  $('#f-type').hide(); 
    $('#gender').hide(); 
                                        
       }
    });
                              

                           });
                           
                        </script>
```

First, select Residential or Commercial. Then #residential div will open if residential select, same for commercial.
Then select a type like Bachelor. If the bachelor selected then show the "Room_type" and "member" and "price" will be hidden. If select apartment/land etc then "price" will be visible and room type, memebr will be hidden.
How can I do this?

Comment: use `onchange` event for the selects then read the value by `$thisselect.val()`, then hide or show elements you want by `$myelement.hide()` and `$myelement.show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onchange` event for your inputs and then write some JS methods to account for different values that have been selected.

In the JS, you can make use of `.show();` or `.hide();` JQuery methods to change the visibility of your divs based on the value that is currently selected.

For example, if we take your scenario of different property types, you can do something like this:

```html
<div class="Property Type">
    <label for=""><input type="radio" onchange="HandlePropertyTypeChange(this);" name="property_type" value="residential"> Residential</label>
    <label for=""><input type="radio" onchange="HandlePropertyTypeChange(this);" name="property_type" value="commercial"> Commercial</label>
</div>
```

And then the JS:

```js
function HandlePropertyTypeChange(radioBtn) {
    if ($(radioBtn).val() == 'residential') {
        $('#residential').show();
        $('#commercial').hide();
    } else if ($(radioBtn).val() == 'commercial') {
        $('#residential').hide();
        $('#commercial').show();        
    } else {
       // Something is different...
    }
}
```

You can apply the same `onchange` logic to the select lists as well if necessary.

Documentation for `.show();`: https://api.jquery.com/show/

Documentation for `.hide();`: https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide

For your select lists, you can do something like this. Again, if we take your concept of what "Residential" type is selected, you can do something like this again:

```html
<div id="residential">
     <select name="" id="" onchange="HandleResidentialTypeChange(this);">
         <option value="1">Apartment</option>
         <option value="2">Becholor</option>
         <option value="3">Sublet</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

And then in JS:

```js
function HandleResidentialTypeChange(selectList) {
    // Handle different values of the select list.
    switch ($(selectList).val()) {
        case "1": // Apartment
             // Do something here
             break;
        case "2": // Becholor
             // Do something here
             break;
        case "3": // Sublet
             // Do something here
             break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made it. But what about select fields.

Comment: The select fields would be the same. You can just add `onchange` to each select field and then take the idea of the JS example I gave you and make some methods to handle the different values. Let me update my answer to provide a bit more help.

Comment: @JahidulIslamTusher Updated my answer based on your question.

Comment: Can you please do one field for me?

Comment: What do you mean one field? Is something unclear about the example I've given?

Comment: I don't understand what's different about what you're asking. The example I have given should cover all of your needs if you use it like I've said.

Comment: Ok, I am giving more effort to implement this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the solution.